# How to zoom out a bitmap image?

Tags: java, android

I'm capturing an image using a biometric reader.
Connecting the reader to the tablet and capturing the image works fine, but the image looks like this:

[image]

The image is cropped. It looks like it's magnified when the biometric capture takes place.

this is my code:

```
package mobfeel.com.br.exfingerprintreaderuareu4500;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import asia.kanopi.fingerscan.Status;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView ivFingerprint;
    private Button btScan;

    private static final int SCAN_FINGERPRINT = 1234;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

        btScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, SCAN_FINGERPRINT);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode){
            case SCAN_FINGERPRINT:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    int status = data.getIntExtra("status", Status.ERROR);

                    if (status == Status.SUCCESS) {
                        toast("Fingerprint OK!");

                        byte[] img = data.getByteArrayExtra("img");
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
                        ivFingerprint.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        return;
                    }
                    toast(data.getStringExtra("errorMessage"));
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    private void toast(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void init(){
        ivFingerprint = findViewById(R.id.ma_iv_fingerprint);
        btScan = findViewById(R.id.ma_bt_scan);
    }
}
```

And this is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ma_iv_fingerprint"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="206dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="460dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ma_bt_scan"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ma_bt_scan"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Scan"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I also have the ScanActivity.java class

```
package mobfeel.com.br.exfingerprintreaderuareu4500;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import asia.kanopi.fingerscan.Fingerprint;
import asia.kanopi.fingerscan.Status;

public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvStatus;

    private Fingerprint fingerprint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

        init();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        fingerprint.scan(ScanActivity.this, printHandler, updateHandler);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        fingerprint.turnOffReader();
        super.onStop();
    }

    Handler updateHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            int status = msg.getData().getInt("status");
            switch (status) {
                case Status.INITIALISED:
                    tvStatus.setText("Setting up reader");
                    break;
                case Status.SCANNER_POWERED_ON:
                    tvStatus.setText("Reader powered on");
                    break;
                case Status.READY_TO_SCAN:
                    tvStatus.setText("Ready to scan finger");
                    break;
                case Status.FINGER_DETECTED:
                    tvStatus.setText("Finger detected");
                    break;
                case Status.RECEIVING_IMAGE:
                    tvStatus.setText("Receiving image");
                    break;
                case Status.FINGER_LIFTED:
                    tvStatus.setText("Finger has been lifted off reader");
                    break;
                case Status.SCANNER_POWERED_OFF:
                    tvStatus.setText("Reader is off");
                    break;
                case Status.SUCCESS:
                    tvStatus.setText("Fingerprint successfully captured");
                    break;
                case Status.ERROR:
                    tvStatus.setText("Error");
                    toast(msg.getData().getString("errorMessage"));
                    break;
                default:
                    tvStatus.setText(String.valueOf(status));
                    toast(msg.getData().getString("errorMessage"));
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    Handler printHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            byte[] image;
            String errorMessage = "";
            int status = msg.getData().getInt("status");

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("status", status);

            if (status == Status.SUCCESS) {
                intent.putExtra("img", msg.getData().getByteArray("img"));
            } else {
                intent.putExtra("errorMessage", msg.getData().getString("errorMessage"));
            }
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    private void toast(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void init() {
        tvStatus = findViewById(R.id.sa_tv_status);
        fingerprint = new Fingerprint();
    }
}
```

activity_scan.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScanActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sa_tv_status"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**What feature can I use to zoom out?**
I appreciate if anyone can help me analyze this!

Comment: `The image is cropped.` What do you mean with cropped? And how would you know? How is what you see determined by `android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="206dp"` ?

Comment: The byte array comes from the ScanActivity.class. What is happening there? Dont you think that that activity has a big influence on the delivered image?

Comment: I added the ScanActivity class. Regarding layout_width and layout_height, whatever value I set, the image remains as is. It gets magnified.

Comment: What do you see when using `android:scaleType="centerInside"`? Is it still the same?

Comment: apparently nothing has changed!

Comment: `intent.putExtra("img", msg.getData().getByteArray("img"));` The big problem with all that code is that we still cannot see where that byte array comes from. msg.getData().getByteArray("img") gets it out of `msg` . But we see no code where it is put in the message. And yet earlier where that byte array comes from. So we can still say nothing.

Comment: See this project, it's the same one I'm using to test the biometric reader. https://github.com/shodgson/uareu